# EF doesn't save or get data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello I have the following code:

This is the Action in the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Category category)
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var currentCategory = CategoriesService.GetCategory(category.Id, currentUserId);
        if (currentCategory != null)
        {
            currentCategory.Name = category.Name;
            CategoriesService.SaveCategory();
        }
        else
        {
            Category toAdd = new Category();
            toAdd.Name = category.Name;
            toAdd.Owner = ApplicationUsersService.GetUser(currentUserId);
            CategoriesService.SaveCategory(toAdd);
        }
        return this.PartialView("_CategoriesListPartial", CategoriesService.GetCategories(currentUserId));
    }
```

And this is the service I am using to save data to the DB

```
    public void SaveCategory()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void SaveCategory(Category category)
    {
        Context.Categories.Add(category);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In the case when i am udpating a model with `currentCategory != null` everything works fine, but in the other the model is not saved in the DB.

Similar issue with another service class

This works fine

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        CategoryViewModel categoriesViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
        categoriesViewModel.Categories = CategoriesService.GetCategories(currentUserId);
        return View(categoriesViewModel);
    }
```

Service

```
        public ICollection<Category> GetCategories(string userId)
    {
        return this.Context.Categories.Where(c => c.Owner.Id == userId && c.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
    }
```

And this doesn't work at all

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        BooksViewModel booksViewModel = new BooksViewModel();
        booksViewModel.Book = new Book();
        booksViewModel.Books = BooksService.GetBooks(currentUserId);
        return View(booksViewModel);
    }
```

Service

```
public ICollection<Book> GetBooks(string userId)
    {
        return this.Context.Books.Where(b => b.Owner.Id == userId && b.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList();
    }
```

Please help

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: Just fixed the case with GetBooks(). The problem with saving the data to context is still a problem

Comment: are you sure Context is the correct object? the highlighting suggests it's a class rather than an object. Anyways, short-lived contexts are generally a better idea than long-lived ones.

Comment: I have a base class DbService which holds the EF context. It is inherited by other service classes which provide logic for getting and saving data to the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really enough to go on here, without seeing `GetCategory()` *in situ*.  I will venture, however: the context *instance* that is being used in `GetCategory()` is not the same as the instance being used in `SaveCategory()`.

Comment: You can see the code here. Controllers: https://github.com/tihomirdimov/CSharp/tree/master/06.CSharpASPNET/02.Project/PersonalFinanceManager/PersonalFinanceManager/Controllers Services: https://github.com/tihomirdimov/CSharp/tree/master/06.CSharpASPNET/02.Project/PersonalFinanceManager/PersonalFinanceManager.Services

Comment: I really can't see anything wrong there.  Have you tried running some acceptance testing against the database?

Comment: Hello. Seems there was a local problem with the either the DB or the PC. When restarted the system, everything was workign fine. Thanks anyways

Comment: Okay, was starting to wonder if this wasn't a local issue.  No need for the "empty" accept--since this is essentially a temporary issue, I'd recommend deleting you question.  No skin off my back.